# Load data by type using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, .net-4.5

I want to do

```
List<ISomeInterface> result = new List<ISomeInterface>();
foreach(Type type in someAssem.GetTypes.IsAssignableFrom(ISomeInterface))
        result.AddRange(LoadType(type));
```

Is it possible load entities by type? I need only load them, no more operation is needed. I prefer using code first and TPT or TPC hierarchy for my solution.

I have seen some generic repositories patterns, but all of them need to pass class. Using Entity Framework 6 and .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `DbSet.Set()` method that is accepting a `Type` argument:

```
public IEnumerable<T> LoadType<T>(Type type)
{
    return context.Set(type).Cast<T>();
}
```

Then:

```
result.AddRange(LoadType<ISomeInterface>(type));
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679544(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: I didnt solved my problems, since i dont have any DbSet in my context. I am dynamily build model on runtime and want to access it non generic DbSet. I am sure if i would have models in my context your solution would helped me.